# How to deal when calling a wrong endpoint using app.get?

Tags: node.js, api, express, http-status-code-403

I have several endpoints defined. I am doing the automation of all of them and in addition defining some scenarios where I should get an error.

For instance, one of the endpoints is: '/v1/templates'.

Now, imagine that by error, the user types '/v1/templatess'.

I am using app.get to deal with the known endpoints like this:

```
app.get(
    '/v1/contents/:template_component_content_id',
    controllers.template_component_contents.getById.bind(controllers.template_component_contents)
);
```

Is there any way to say that in case that the endpoint called does not match with any of the app.get() options, throw an ERROR?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In `app.js` write this below where you've imported `routes`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  res.status(404).send({message:"Not Found"});
});
```

if you want to display some page from backend

```
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  res.render('./path/to/file');
});
```

For more reference check this github project

[nodejs_boiler_plate/app.js](https://github.com/Atishay96/boiler_plate/blob/master/app.js)

Answer (score 4):

You can handle 404 withing express handlers.

In your main express file(may be index.js or app.js) just put following after your routing middleware.

```
app.use("/v1", your_router);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((request, response, next) => {
  // Access response variable and handle it
  // response.status(404).send("Your page is not found"))
  // or
  // res.render("home")
});
```

You can achieve this with additional route also with

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {})
```

But it's not advisable as it's regex operation and express already providing the inbuilt handler to handle 404 routes.

Answer (score 1):

Try Something Like:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send({error: "No routes matched"});
  res.end();
})
```

Add this code as a last route in your routes and i hope so will do the magic.